# Как оформлять интервалы чисел (градусы по Цельсию)?

Tags: оформление-текста

К примеру: 15-20 °С; +15-20 °С;...
А как быть с отрицательными значениями? -15-20 °С?

Comment: На ТВ когда-то писали через многоточие: "-15...-20 °С". А вообще говоря, минус "–", тире "—" и дефис "-" — три разных знака.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> А как быть с отрицательными значениями?

В бумажном Мильчине (2003) так:

[image: Употребление тире]

Comment: Интересно! А мне нравится такая запись:   от -15 до -20. Просто, ясно, по крайней мере для русскоязычного населения.